# Set up table view without delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a **UITableView** in view controller. I want to set up the view, properties etc for the table view without setting a **UITableViewDelegate or UITableViewDataSource delegate**.

Is it possible programmatically? (something like `[tableView setNumberOfSections:2]`)

Comment: Why do you want to do it in this way.Any specific reason.

Comment: simplicity is writing the code in the easy and the standard way nor just to make the three lines of code to one line.

Comment: Sometime doing these experiments in the app causes the reason of rejection on appstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible. But maybe it's an option for you to use a static tableview? There you don't need a delegate, but your number of rows / sections is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can set

```
myTableView.delegate = self;
myTableView.dataSource = self;
```

and then add the code for the methods in the same class (so you don't need to create new custom classes).

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and why would you want to do that? The system of using delegates is there to give you the most flexible solution possible, you don't have to use all the delegate and datasource methods. It's just the way it works to make it possible to completely customise your table should you choose to, but a basic implementation is almost no work.

You can use any class as the delegate just by adopting the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols, so you don't need to create any specialised class. Just use your viewController for example.